# Syntax error in migrating from SQL Server 2008 to MySQL using SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, data-migration

This is my first SSIS package and I have followed some tutorials and everything looked good until I ran it. I am trying to sync the data from a SQL Server 2008 database to a MySQL database (only 1 table with 2 columns). After running the package I get the following error.

> *[ADO NET Destination [16]] Error: An exception has occurred during
>   data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"UPC", "Model")
>   VALUES (p1, p2)' at line 1*

And on the next line

> [SSIS.Pipeline]
>   Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.
>   The ProcessInput method on component "ADO NET Destination" (16) failed with error code 0xC020844B while processing input "ADO NET Destination Input" (19).
>   The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

My questions are:

1. Why I am getting this error ?
2. How to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the MSDN link about problems with ADO.NET and MySQL:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2009/01/07/writing-to-a-mysql-database-from-ssis.aspx

From the MSDN document:

Note, I recommend using the ODBC Driver when writing to the MySQL database, because the MySQL .NET Connector has an additional blocking issue. If you try it out, you’ll get an error which looks something like this:

```
Error: 2009-01-05 12:03:47.79 
   Code: 0xC020844B 
   Source: Data Flow Task 1 Destination - Query [28] 
   Description: An exception has occurred during data insertion, 
                the message returned from the provider is: 
                You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
                to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
                '"name", "date", "type", "remark") 
                VALUES (p1, p2, p3, p4), (p1,p2,p3,p4), (p1,p2' at line 1 
End Error
```

Note that the “VALUES” portion has parameter names, and not the actual values. This appears to be an issue with the value the MySQL provider returns for its ParameterMarkerFormat. I did find a bug that was opened against them, but it looks like they decided not to fix it. I’ve heard that the DevArt dotConnect drivers do not have this problem, but I haven’t been able to try them out myself.

Comment: I have seen this url before. It is from 2009 and i was hoping that some better solution might exist now.